# Converting 64-bit unsigned int (in hex string form) to decimal in java

Tags: java, long-integer, unsigned

I have a hex string that represents a 64-bit unsigned int.

I want to convert this to a decimal representation in java.

I wanted to use `Long.parseLong("HexString", 16);` but in java the leftmost bit is the sign bit and any number greater than 2^31-1 would not fit.

SO how do i convert and store this data?

Thanks, 
Sunny

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a `BigInteger` using the [constructor that takes a `String` and an `int` radix](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-java.lang.String-int-).

```
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(hexString, 16);
```

If you have Java 8, you can use [`Long.parseUnsignedLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseUnsignedLong-java.lang.String-int-), which will allow you to parse all 64 bits, even if the bit that would normally put it over `Long.MAX_VALUE` is set.  It still returns a `long`, which in Java is still signed, but it will be parsed as if it were an unsigned `long`.

```
long stillSigned = Long.parseUnsignedLong(hexString, 16);
```

If the value that gets parsed is negative, then the true unsigned value is the signed value + 2<sup>64</sup>.